# Snowflake Incremental Load using Last updated timestamp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to do incremental load in snowflake? Both source and target are SF tables. what is the best way we can do for incremental load with last updated timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

Highly recommend you look at Snowflake STREAMS.  This will allow you to do incremental changes without the need to track the updated timestamp.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html

Answer (score 1):

Merge would be the right option for incremental data load. Assuming you have source and target unique record identifier .

Merge into 
....
When matched
... 
WHEN NOT MATCHED

Please check below link

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Answer (score 1):

[Incremental Load In Snowflake](https://blogs.perficient.com/2022/07/06/how-to-implement-incremental-loading-in-snowflake-using-stream-and-merge/)

Incremental operations using Snowflake Stream and Merge Statement is fast and it's perfectly working fine with a data volume of 950 millions rows in the target table. Incremental Checks are quite fast and perform the upsert and delete operation within 2 minutes.`

**Source table** - "SALES"."CUSTOMERSALES"."CUSTOMER_DETAILS"

**Target table** - "CUSTOMERMASTER"."SALES"."CUSTOMER"

**/* Creating the Stream object for the Source table CDC */**

CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS STRM_CUSTOMER_DETAILS
ON TABLE "SALES"."CUSTOMERSALES"."CUSTOMER_DETAILS"

1. DESC STREAM "SALES"."CUSTOMERSALES".STRM_CUSTOMER_DETAILS
2. SHOW STREAMS

[MERGE STATEMENT TO PERFORM THE INCREMENTAL OPERATIONS ON THE TARGET TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHir1.png)